# Find the UMVUE of $6\theta^2$ given $f(x\mid\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta^2} e^{\frac{-\sqrt{x}}{\theta}} I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$

Tags: self-study, point-estimation, umvue

Given $X_1, X_2,\ldots, X_n$ are i.i.d rvs with pdf $f(x\mid\theta) = \frac{1}{2\theta^2} e^{\frac{-\sqrt{x}}{\theta}} I_{(0,\infty)}(x)$  for $\ \theta > 0$. Find the UMVUE of $\ 6\theta^2$, and compute its variance.

**My thought:** We see that since $E(\overline{X}) = 6\theta^2$, $\overline{X}$ is an unbiased estimator of $\ 6\theta^2$. Now, since these random variables belong to an exponential family, and $w(\theta) = \frac{-1}{\theta}$ whose range is an open set in $\mathbb R^1$,  it's a well-known fact that $\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{X_i}$ is a complete statistic, and it's also a sufficient statistics (by Factorization theorem). But unfortunately, $\overline{X}$ is not a function of this complete sufficient statistics $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}$, so I cannot apply Lehmann - Scheffe theorem to conclude that $\overline{X}$ is a UMVUE of $\theta$. Or am I completely on the wrong track, since $\overline{X}$ is **NOT** a UMVUE of $\theta$ ??

I also tried with the unbiased estimator $\ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{X_i}}{2n}$ but this one does not have the variance equal to Cramer-Rao Lower Bound $=\frac{72\theta^4}{n},$ so it's not the UMVUE of $6\theta^2$ either.

**My question:** Can anyone please help me with this problem? I'm getting stuck on it for a while despite trying various unbiased estimator...

Comment: @Michael Chernick: could you help by giving this problem a try??

Comment: Nobody wants to help me witht his problem? It's probably too easy for you guys, but it's hard for me:(

Comment: @MichaelChernick: I added it. Hopefully you could lend a hand now;)

Comment: You should also note that your posting time is about 2:00 AM on the east coast of the U.S., 11:00 PM on the west coast, so you're not going to get as many responses in just a few hours as you would if you waited a full day.

Comment: @jbowman: appreciate your comment. I have been trying to do it myself and waiting...waiting..;p

Comment: If $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}/2n$ is complete and sufficient and unbiased, then it is a UMVUE. Sometimes UMVUEs don't attain the Cramer-Rao Lower Bound

Comment: @Greeparker: My apology for this question, but we only have $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}$ is complete sufficient (due to these rvs belong to an exponen tial family). So how do we know $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}}{2n}$ is also complete sufficient?

Comment: @user177196 Ok, $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}$ is complete and sufficient, and $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}/2n$ is a function of a complete and sufficient statistic, and its unbiased. Thus by Lehman-Scheffe's theorem, it is UMVUE. See the [statement of the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmann%E2%80%93Scheff%C3%A9_theorem#Statement)

Comment: Wait a minute. The sum you mentioned is unbiased only for $\theta$, not $6\theta^2$?! We are finding UMVUE for $6\theta^2$, not $\theta$;)

Comment: @user177196 Ah, ok. I didn't do any of the computation, and was reading from what you wrote. "I also tried with the unbiased estimator  $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}/2n$" You might want to say what it's unbiased for here. So now since $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}/2n$ is unbiased for $\theta$ you can try and see if there is constant $c$ such that $c \left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}/2n \right)^2$ is unbiased for $6 \theta^2$. If yes, then you have a UMVUE.

Comment: Arghhh.. I realized why I got stuck. There is such $c = \frac{2n+1}{2n}$ (is this correct??) that makes $c(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i}/2n)^2$, but then when I computed its variance, the variance is not equal to CRLB, so I thought it's not UMVUE. Anyway, you are using Lehmann-Scheffe's theorem here right? And the variance would be $\frac{18\theta^2}{n(2n+1)^2}$?

Comment: @user177196 I haven't worked out the math (this is self-study), so I just gave you the hint, that the CR lower bound need not be attained and the Lehmann-Scheffe's theorem applies still. The technicalities are for you to figure out.

Comment: I worked it out already. But I'm just not sure, because it's ugly:p And it's not clear to me that the variance is  $> \frac{72\theta^4}{n}$ which is the CRLB for any unbiased estimators of $6\theta^2$. Could you actually try working out the math so that I could see if i did something wrong?

Comment: @Greenparker: I got the first part of the question above. But now I'm currently stuck on computing the variance, as I would need to compute $E((\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sqrt{X_i})^4). Could you please show me how to compute this without using multinomial theorem?

Comment: I will provide the solutions in class tonight. I do not like that my students are using this site to get unauthorized help on homework problems. Why not ask me for a hint? C. Sutton

Comment: "this one does not have the variance equal to Cramer-Rao Lower Bound [ . . . . . ], so it's not the UMVUE" $$\S$$ Are you sure the UMVUE always achieves the Cramér–Rao lower bound? Nothing in the Cramér–Rao theorem says that in every instance it is the GREATEST lower bound. (Right now I don't know a counterexample, but I'll look around. Maybe you've got one right here.) $\qquad$

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted and answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212510/find-umvue-of-6-theta2-given-fx-mid-theta-frac12-theta2-e-frac.